# == vs is in PyCharm

Tags: equals, pycharm

Hello I am new to python.
Does Python IDLE and Pycharm handle `is` and `==` statements differently? In Python IDLE I get `false` for the statement `apple is orange` and in PyCharm it seems to return `true`.

I had set both `apple = 500` and `orange = 500`. In python IDLE I got `false` for `apple is orange`, as I had expected, since they are different objects. I got `true` for `apple == orange` since both are equal to 500. In Pycharm community edition I set up if statements to test the same statements and I got `true` for both.

Unfortunately I can not upload a screenshot due to my reputation not being 10.

Comment: It's not a PyCharm problem, it's a semantic difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does comparing strings in Python using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `is` unless you know what you are doing. If `a is b`, then `a` points to exact same memory address as `b`. `==`, on the other hand, implements the expected concept of equality.